# ASP.NET MVC - Bootstrap-Modal Pop-Up, Nothing is Opened When I Click on the Button

Tags: asp.net-mvc, popup, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to pop up with bootstrap. In my "NoteListPartial.cshtml" page; if I click on the edit button, I want the "Not.cshtml" to be opened with pop up. But when I click button, nothing happens. My codes is as follows:

This is my "NoteListPartial.cshtml":

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Note", "Project", new { ID = item.ID,ProjectID=item.ProjectID })" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#notedetailModal">Edit</a>
```

And this is my "Note.cshtml":

```
<div class="modal" id="notedetailModal" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title"><b>Edit Note</b></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="note note-info">
                            <h4 class="block"><b>Note Content:</b></h4>
                            <textarea name="Content" style="width: 230px">@Model.Content</textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg blue" value="Add Note" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is there any javascript error in console?

Comment: I have posted on answer please check also you can remove href and set Data-load-url to set your action link

Comment: You are missing bootstrap-datetimepicker.js as error giving for that. first resolve error of js and then try agian it will work

Answer (score 0):

Can you please add below code role="dialog" like

```
<div class="modal" id="notedetailModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
```

Answer (score 0):

remove url from anchor tag and change div role as dialog

```
<a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#notedetailModal">Edit</a>
```

and

```
 <div class="modal" id="notedetailModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
```

model will popup but for edit window you need to add with ajax type content request on click you need to do like this following like : [Render Partial View As Modal Popup Using AJAX Call with JSON](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/render-partial-view-as-modal-popup-using-ajax-call-with-json/)

Comment: i updated the answer and check whether any error message showing in browser console .. for the date picker issue you need to import js of bootstrap datepicker and moment.js